# How can I detect when TextField is tapped? (SwiftUI on MacOS)

Tags: swift, swiftui, touch, textfield, gesture

How can I detect when a TextField is tapped? (SwiftUI on MacOS)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var field: String = "TextField"
  
  var body: some View {
    TextField("Fill in Text", text: $field)
      .onTapGesture {
        print("Textfield pressed")
    }
  }
}
```

When the TextField is tapped it doesn't print "Textfield pressed".
I'm guessing this is because the tap is picked up by the TextField before it can be detected by the Textfield gesture.

Answer (score 8):

### New Method (not backward compatible)

There is a new wrapper called `@FocusState` that controls the state of the keyboard and the focused keyboard ('aka' firstResponder).

#### Detect Focused State

you can observe on the changes of the `@FocusState`  variable with `.onChange` modifier

#### Become First Responder ( Focused )

If you use a `focused` modifier on the text fields, you can make them become focused, for example, you can set the `focusedField` property in the code to make the binded textField become active:

[image]

#### Resign first responder ( Dismiss keyboard )

or dismiss the keyboard by setting the variable to `nil`:

[image]

Don't forget to watch the **Direct and reflect focus in SwiftUI** session from WWDC2021

---

### Old Method (backward compatible and forward compatible)

Instead of Taping, You can detect when `TextField` is focused easily inside `onEditingChanged`:

```
TextField("Fill in Text", text: $field, onEditingChanged: { focused in
    print(focused ? "focused" : "unfocused")
}
```

Comment: This is wrong, with this approach you detect `onEditingChanged` and nothing else. If you only tap on the textfield this will not fire.

Answer (score 6):

The `.simultaneousGesture` modifier does what you need.

Here is an example:

```
struct TestTextTap: View {
    @State var field: String = "TextField"

    var body: some View {
      TextField("Fill in Text", text: $field)
        .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
          print("Textfield pressed")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Asperi for your response. On my machine this works on iOS simulator but does not work running as a macOS app which is what I need!

Comment: Is there any way to get part of text of textfield?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the intended results, but it feels slightly hacky until macOS can register a tap inside the text field.

I overlaid an almost transparent rectangle on top of the TextField. If the tap was sensed at that point, the TextField would not be selectable, but in SwiftUI you can make it the focus by using a @FocusState boolean.

So when the onTapGesture is sensed, it will change the @FocusState variable to true, which will let the user type into the TextField.

The little differences in macOS that make everything so much more complicated are maddening at times.

```
    @State var field: String = "TextField"
    @FocusState private var textFieldIsFocused: Bool

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Fill in Text", text: $field)
            .focused($textFieldIsFocused)
            .overlay((Color.white.opacity(0.0001)))
            .onTapGesture {
                self.textFieldIsFocused = true
                print("Textfield pressed")
            }
    }
```

Sorry, edited because I realized I did not include the .focused method!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `.simultaneousGesture` did not work for me on macOS, but what worked was to use [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) to get the NSTextField and add a `NSClickGestureRecognizer` to it.

Then I added a `@StateObject` to handle the target/action.